# How to parse several positional arguments with nargs='+'

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, argparse

Here's a short summary of what I am trying to achieve:

- Get one or more (tabular) files
- Look for a particular string key (at the moment there's just a single key, but I can imagine expanding this to take in multiple keys)
- The rows that match the key, extract the character(s) at a given position, or range of positions.

So in an ideal world I'd like to run my script in the following ways, they are all valid use cases:

```
python myscript.py file1 file2 file3 "key" 10
python myscript.py file1 file2 "key" 10 12
python myscript.py file1 "key" 10 12
python myscript.py file1 "key" 10
```

Given the use case I tried:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("files", nargs='+', help="input files")
parser.add_argument("gene", help="gene of interest")
parser.add_argument("pos", nargs='+', type=int, help="position(s) to analyze")

""" Validate pos """
if len(args.pos) > 2:
    sys.exit("Positions argument needs to be a single integer or two integers denoting a range!")

...

# in some other function
if len(args.pos) == 1:
    key = row[SIND][args.pos[0]]
elif len(args.pos) == 2:
    key = row[SIND][args.pos[0] : args.pos[1]]
else:
    print(args.pos, len(args.pos))
    sys.exit("args.pos assertion failed!")
```

It works when there is only one integer but not when I send two integers to analyze a range instead. In the latter case the "key" is interpreted as a file as well thus I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IGHV4-39'`.

**Question1:** Is it possible to flag or indicate positional arguments, so that I can tell argparse when the `files` parameter ends and `gene` starts? I don't want to make them optional arguments, since the logic of the script is incomplete if either of the three parameters is omitted.

**Question2:** Is it otherwise helpful to divide the pos parameter into two; pos which takes a single integer, and range which takes two integers, then make them somehow exclusive?

Any ideas?

Comment: Either you use flagged arguments (yes, they can be required), or you parse `sys.argv` yourself.  Your logic seems to favor parsing that list from the end:  e.g. pull off the trailing integers, the key string, and the rest are file names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer for Question 1

"Is it possible to flag ... positional arguments?" Well, if you did that, then they wouldn't be positional arguments anymore! Since after all positional arguments are defined by being in position, not by being flagged.

I think all you really need is the `required` option, and not to try and be too clever using positional arguments. Is your aim to create an amazingly clever interface that magically works out what it is you want regardless of input, or an interface that works predictably and produces good error messages?

*I can be sarcastic on this point because I have spent far too much time in the past doing the first instead of just doing the second.*

So why not this:

#### test.py

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--files', required=True, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--genes', required=True, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument(
    '--pos', required=True, nargs='+', type=int, help="position(s) to analyze")

opts = parser.parse_args()
print(dir(parser))

print('files: %s, genes: %s, poses: %s' % (
    opts.files, opts.genes, opts.pos))
```

So:

```
$ python test.py
usage: test.py [-h] --files FILES [FILES ...] --genes GENES [GENES ...] --pos
           POS [POS ...]
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: --files, --genes, --pos

$ python test.py --files file1 file2 --genes xzy --pos 2 1
files: ['file1', 'file2'], genes: ['xzy'], poses: [2, 1]
```

### Answer for Question 2

Aren't you essentially asking "what is the best interface here"? Surely that's something you need to decide. My advice: keep it simple. Why not do:

```
parser.add_argument('--start', '-s', required=True, nargs=1, type=int)
parser.add_argument('--end', '-e', nargs=1, type=int)

opts = parser.parse_args()
if opts.end is None:
    opts.end = opts.start + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick implementation of a `sys.argv` parse:

```
In [97]: txt='file1 file2 file3 "key" 10 12'
In [98]: argv=txt.split()
In [99]: argv
Out[99]: ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', '"key"', '10', '12']
In [104]: files,rows,key=[],[],None
In [105]: for a in argv[::-1]:
     ...:     try:
     ...:         rows.append(int(a))
     ...:     except ValueError:
     ...:         if key is None: key=a
     ...:         else: files.append(a)
     ...:         
In [106]: files
Out[106]: ['file3', 'file2', 'file1']
In [107]: rows
Out[107]: [12, 10]
In [108]: key
Out[108]: '"key"'
```

You could even use `parse_known_args` to handle other flagged arguments, and apply this logic to unparse `extras`.

`argparse` handles arguments from left to right; your positional logic fits the reverse better.  Flags (`optionals`) provide well defined dividers between argument strings.  Without them, parsing muliple `+` arguments is impossible.  The first '+' is greedy (think of `regex` behavior), and grabs all.  And when allocating strings to arguments, it does not check types.  Type conversion (e.g. to `int`) occurs after the string has been allocated.

Comment: The problem with this is that you're recommending parsing the arguments yourself, rather than learning how to use argparse properly. argparse is very powerful, so even if it doesn't quite do what the OP wants, it's better advice in the long term IMO for them to adjust slightly what they want to fit with argparse. That's just good advice in general: fit into a well-used framework, don't roll your own. Far less to test!

Comment: `argparse` is a tool, not a rule.